# When I'm using phantomJS in node, the error appeared

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm using phantomJS in node and wrote the following code, but the error appeared on the console.

The following code simply tries to access the google top page and take a screen shot of its page.

How should I resolve this error?

(node version: v6.10.3)

(1) code(test.js)

```
var phantom = require("phantom");
var promise = phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
    return ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
        page.property('onConsoleMessage', function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
        page.property('onLoadStarted', function() {
            loadInProgress = true;
            console.log('Load Started...');
        });
        page.property('onLoadFinished', function() {
            loadInProgress = false;
            console.log('Load End');
        });

        var loadInProgress = false;
        var stepIndex = 0;
        var steps = [
            function() {
                page.open('https://www.google.co.jp/').then(function (status) {
                    // something process
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error); // <======= Here, the error appeared
                });
            },
            function() {
                console.log("step end");
            }
        ];

        interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(!loadInProgress && typeof steps[stepIndex] == 'function') {
                steps[stepIndex]();
                stepIndex++;
            } else if (steps[stepIndex] != 'function') {
                ph.exit();
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 10);
    });
});
```

(2) error

```
$ node test.js
step end
warn: exit() was called before waiting for commands to finish. Make sure you are not calling exit() too soon.
info: Load Started...
Error: Phantom process stopped with exit code 0
    at Phantom._rejectAllCommands (<myfilepath>/phantomjs/node_modules/phantom/lib/phantom.js:361:41)
    at ChildProcess.Phantom.process.on.code (<myfilepath>/phantomjs/node_modules/phantom/lib/phantom.js:164:18)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exit the script too early, exactly as the error says.

Remove `ph.exit();` from the interval function:

```
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(!loadInProgress && typeof steps[stepIndex] == 'function') {
            steps[stepIndex]();
            stepIndex++;
        } else if (steps[stepIndex] != 'function') {
            // ph.exit(); // <-- remove exit() from here
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 10);
```

Move it instead into `page.open` callback for it to be called after the page is opened:

```
page.open('https://www.google.co.jp/').then(function (status) {
    ph.exit();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer to the above, and I was able to solve this problem